# Cannot Initialize Kinect in Windows (0 sensors detected)

Tags: c++, windows, sdk, initialization, kinect

I cannot initalize Kinect v1 in my Windows PC.

This is my code (it builds successfully):

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Ole2.h>

#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <gl/GLU.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>

#include <NuiApi.h>
#include <NuiImageCamera.h>
#include <NuiSensor.h>

#define width 640
#define height 480

// Kinect variables
HANDLE rgbStream;              // The identifier of the Kinect's RGB Camera
INuiSensor* sensor;            // The kinect sensor


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Get a working kinect sensor
    int numSensors=1;
    HRESULT reponse;
    reponse = NuiGetSensorCount(&numSensors);
    if (reponse < 0)  return false;
    if (numSensors < 1) return false;
    if (NuiCreateSensorByIndex(0, &sensor) < 0) return false;

    // Initialize sensor
    sensor->NuiInitialize(NUI_INITIALIZE_FLAG_USES_DEPTH | NUI_INITIALIZE_FLAG_USES_COLOR);
    sensor->NuiImageStreamOpen(
        NUI_IMAGE_TYPE_COLOR,            // Depth camera or rgb camera?
        NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_640x480,    // Image resolution
        0,        // Image stream flags, e.g. near mode
        2,        // Number of frames to buffer
        NULL,   // Event handle
        &rgbStream);
    return sensor;
}
```

The problem is that the function "NuiGetSensorCount" returns always that the number of sensors is 0.

The Kinect 1 is plugged in to the PC through the USB port (I've tried in different ports); and the curious thing is that, if I run software like Skanect (1.8 Win64), Skanect recognizes the device (it's detected as OpenNI 2 Sensor) and I'm able to use it.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Update 5, in Windows 7 64-bit.
I have installed OpenNI 64-bit 2 drivers and Kinect for Windows SDK v1.8.

In my project properties, I am calling the Kinect10.lib library located at:

- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Kinect\v1.8\lib\x86
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Kinect\v1.8\lib\amd64

(I've tried in both x86 and x64 configurations)

Likewise, for each configurationI've tried using the Kinect10.dll binaries located at:

- C:\Windows\System32
- C:\Windows\SysWOW64

Any comments/suggestions are greatly welcomed.
Also, if I have missed some information you think is relevant, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
I just saw that you already call The Initializer function. Maybe you need to call that prior to your NuiGetSensorCount(&numSensors) function.

I do not have much experience with the NUI framework, but I'd recommend using the OpenNI framework for the kinect camera. Although alreay discontinued its quite stable and works very well. It even supports callback functions for grabbed images and so on.

Heres the link:
http://structure.io/openni

But from what I've found on the internet, it seems that you are following this tutorial: 
http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~edwardz/tutorials/kinect/kinect1.html

I've found another one  [here](https://electroniclunch.wordpress.com/2013/01/14/kinect-tutorial-c/)

It seems to call an Initializer function before reading the number of sensors:

```
[...]
int main()
{
   cout << "Hello world" << endl;
   NuiInitialize(NUI_INITIALIZE_FLAG_USES_SKELETON);  <-------- HERE
   NUI_SKELETON_FRAME ourframe;
   while (1)
   {
     NuiSkeletonGetNextFrame(0, &ourframe);
     for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
     {
       if (ourframe.SkeletonData[i].eTrackingState == NUI_SKELETON_TRACKED)
         cout << "Right Hand: " ;
         cout << ourframe.SkeletonData[i].SkeletonPositions[NUI_SKELETON_POSITION_HAND_RIGHT].y << endl;
     }
     system("cls");
   }
  NuiShutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

Where NuiInitialize points to [the msdn doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/nuiapi.nuiinitialize.aspx?tduid=(f0f5a11a9d304602ca52c6b6c85e547a)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-_EgMPws3DiDM8a8w2R6sdQ)())

which says

> Specifies the Kinect subsystems to initialize

This seems to enable the Kinect Subsystem which would of ocurse be necessary to start up the device.

Let me know if that worked!

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
I tried calling _NuiInitialize_ at the very beginning; but it didn't help.
I think it needs to be called for a given sensor, and that's why in the tutorial it's used after the sensor has been created.
As for using the OpenNI framework instead, I'm working on that; but it seems it will take me some time to check.

Comment: I dont know how thats possible if the other application detects the device... but try plugging in the kinect on a powered usb hub.